# Identify irrelevant queries based on context

Tags: text-mining

I'm working on keyphrase extraction from individual queries using R/Python.

However, is there any way I can detect whether the query is valid in a particular context or not ? 
Find an example scenario here:

```
Query1 = 'I need to order a birthday cake. Cherry topped vanilla cream over chocolate.'
Query2 = 'I wish to have a butterscotch cake with caramel sauce on top.'
Query3 = 'I need to throw my chocolate wrapper into the dustbin.'
```

Assuming the context is Cake customization, let's say `Query1`, `Query2` are valid, but `Query3` is not. `Query3` is clearly not about cake customization, while the first two queries are about cake customization.

If I want to eliminate the invalid queries prior to my key-phrase extraction step. Any help in the approach to be taken is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of doing some clustering as pre-processing step. Cluster the queries so that no queries in a cluster looks irrelevant. To compare queries for clustering, you can generate some query representation using say Bag-of-Word model using TF-IDF weights and then use cosine similarity to find out which queries are similar.

If you are interested in advanced approach, then you can think of deep learning techniques. There are many deep learning techniques which is designed to do this kind of task. But to keep things simple, you can train a deep neural network to generate query/sentence representations.

Actually you don't need to that because there exists many pre-trained models. For example, [skip-thought vectors](https://github.com/ryankiros/skip-thoughts) can produce sentence representation (vectors) for your queries. Then you can use it to compare queries for clustering.